# forms con pasos

Tags: html

Tengo un formulario, dividido en fielsets, al iniciar la pagina solo se mostrara el primero oculatando el otro fielset, y que al presionar el boton de siguiente
cambie automaticamente al otro fielset con ayuda de javascript o jquery, como puedo lograr el ocultamiento y la transicion al sigueinte,

al final tengo mi archivo de js llamado "cambios"

gracias

```html
<body style="padding:0px;">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="title" style="width:30%; float:right">
                            <div class="panel-heading">opciones</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle">
                                    <option>Si</option>
                                    <option>No</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

             
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h5>TITULO</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                             <label>EJEMPLO DE TEXTO<label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="title">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">


                                    <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">
                                        <H5>TITULO</H5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <label>EJEMPLO DE TEXTO</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2" onclick="siguiente()">Siguiente</button>
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2" onclick="anterior()">Anterior</button>

            </fieldset>
            <!--FINAL DEL PRIMER PASO-->
            
            
            <!--SEGUNDO PASO-->
             <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="title" style="width:30%; float:right">
                            <div class="panel-heading">opciones</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle">
                                    <option>Si</option>
                                    <option>No</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2" onclick="siguiente()">Siguiente</button>
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2" onclick="anterior()">Anterior</button>

            </fieldset>
            
        </form>
    </div>
    
    
     <script src="../Js/cambio.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Pero intentaste algo? sabes que tenes que mostrar lo que intentaste....

Comment: Por favor visita y lee de nuevo el [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). La explicación que proporcionas no es clara, no ayuda a la comunidad a poder saber exactamente tu problema, desde el título hasta el contenido de tu pregunta. Por favor edítala para que más personas que tengan el mismo problema que tú puedan encontrar una solución, así como las personas que intenten ayudarte sepan en dónde se encuentra tu problema y así tener más probabilidades de recibir ayuda de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veamos si solo tienes dos fieldset pues la cosa es fácil: cambiarle el display. Estas funciones ocultan uno y muestran el otro.
El html ponle un **id="filed1"** al *primer fieldset* y un **id="field2"** al *segundo fieldset*, esto te va a servir para identificarlos en los scripts.

```js
function siguiente()
{
document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("field1").style.display = "none";
}

function anterior()
{
document.getElementById("field1").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "none";
}
```

Si hay más bloques la solución es similar, pero hay que poner todos en oculto, excepto uno que se pondrá en visible. De alguna manera tienes que identificar al visible (con un class o con un id...).